# PHP: Handling both exceptions and errors

Tags: php, error-handling, exception

I want to create a simple exceptions and errors handler with php, so I google for something similar and I found these 3 PHP functions:
`set_exception_handler(functionName)`
`set_error_handler(functionName)`
`register_shutdown_function(functionName)`
But it seems that I can't get the results I want and here is why:
I did 3 simple tests:
**TEST 1**

```
function exceptionHandler(Exception $e){
    echo 'this is exception: '.$e->getMessage();
}

function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    echo 'this is error';
}

set_exception_handler("exceptionHandler");
set_error_handler("errorHandler");    
register_shutdown_function('errorHandler');

throw new Exception('excepp');
```

**Result:** The exception handler works fine and handle the exception.
**TEST2**

```
function exceptionHandler(Exception $e){
    echo 'this is exception: '.$e->getMessage();
}

function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    echo 'this is error';
}

set_exception_handler("exceptionHandler");
set_error_handler("errorHandler");
register_shutdown_function('errorHandler');

$a = $foo;//---unkown $foo variable
```

**Result:** The error handler works fine and handle the error.
**TEST3**

```
function exceptionHandler(Exception $e){
    echo 'this is exception: '.$e->getMessage();
}

function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    echo 'this is error';
}

set_exception_handler("exceptionHandler");
set_error_handler("errorHandler");    
register_shutdown_function('errorHandler');

$a = $foo();//---unkown $foo() function
```

**Result:** The error handler does not work as expected and I get this "unhandled" error.
[image]

**TEST4**

```
function exceptionHandler(Exception $e){
    echo 'this is exception: '.$e->getMessage();
}

function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    echo 'this is error';
}

set_exception_handler("exceptionHandler");
set_error_handler("errorHandler");    
register_shutdown_function('errorHandler');

$a = $foo //---forgot the ';' (Parse error)
```

**Result:** Here also the error handler does not work as expected and I get this.
[image]

So my objectif is to redirect any type of error or exception to a specific class and display something more elegant, but as you can see I can't handle all errors so maybe I'm missing something here. Hope you guys helps me.

Comment: Xdebug does and handles a lot of things, try disabling it. Most fatal errors have been converted to exceptions in PHP7.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois thnx for your answer, but how can I disable xdebug? and also how can symfony handle any kind of errors if fatal errors cannot be catched ?!

Comment: To actually catch syntax errors and such, you have to register a shutdown function before the file gets parsed. That means you have to prepend a file which registers a shutdown function, to actually catch following syntax errors. Files that contain syntax errors, do not get run at all (it's logical).

Comment: You can disable xdebug in the php.ini, iirc `xdebug.enable = 0` disables it. The xdebug website is down currently, so I can't really check.

Comment: Most fatal errors have been converted to exceptions in PHP7, thus you can catch them. In PHP5 fatal errors trigger a shutdown, so you can do the stuff you need to gracefully close the request (e.g. write some stuff to file and display response (e.g. error page)).

Comment: @CharlotteDunois thnx for your time :)